# Why does my satellite modem/router have 2 IP addresses on the LAN side?

Tags: networking

I hope this isn't too general of a question...

I'm confused by the output of ipconfig:

---

IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.42.23(Preferred)

Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.42.1

DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.42.1

DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1,
                                    192.168.0.1

---

Specifically, why are the addresses for default gateway and DNS servers different? Conceptually, it seems to me they should be the same.

I understand the fact that the router has its own DHCP server and it hands out the IP addresses on my local subnet, and I also understand that the router obtains DNS info from my ISP (HughesNet) so it can act as a DNS server on the local subnet. It's one device though, so why aren't the gateway, DHCP, and DNS addresses all the same?

I thought maybe it's because the internal wireless NIC on the router would have a different IP address than the wired connection on the router, so I disconnected from wireless and plugged an ethernet cable directly into the router, but I get the same output from ipconfig.

In my browser, both 192.168.0.1 and 192.168.42.1 take me to the router's web page, but Tracert to 192.168.0.1 goes through 192.168.42.1 Can someone explain what I'm not understanding here?

Comment: Do you have multiple routers chained? Do you use phone USB tethering in this example?

Comment: I wonder if it's done so (by having the DNS server in another subnet) because it allows simpler firewalling between the different subnets. Like, the `192.168.0.0/24` subnet is one that hosts "shared" services like DNS so that e.g. a "guest" subnet (say, `192.168.56.0/24`) can access it without being able to access `192.168.42.0/24`.

Comment: I wonder if you can still have domain names resolved if you set the DNS server(s) to 192.168.42.1 on the "client".

Comment: Nope, doesn't resolve if I tell Windows to use default gateway as DNS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Specifically, why are the addresses for default gateway and DNS servers different?

They are different due to the fact the device has been configured so that the default gateway and DNS servers are not identical.  The only purpose of the default gateway is to serve as a forwarding host to other networks when no other route is specified.

Source: [Default gateway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Default_gateway)

> I understand the fact that the router has its own DHCP server and it hands out the IP addresses on my local subnet, and I also understand that the router obtains DNS info from my ISP (HughesNet) so it can act as a DNS server on the local subnet. It's one device though, so why aren't the gateway, DHCP, and DNS addresses all the same?

It is not a requirement for them to be identical.

> In my browser, both 192.168.0.1 and 192.168.42.1 take me to the router's web page, but Tracert to 192.168.0.1 goes through 192.168.42.1 Can someone explain what I'm not understanding here?

Since your default gateway is `192.168.42.1`, traffic would be redirected to your router on your network, since your DNS server (the router) is also the gateway.  Y**ou should be able to go into the configuration of the device and set the DNS server and the default gateway to the same IPv4 address if you want.**